# Daemon Apps and Scopes

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

So, I am trying to do see if I can support a scenario where a C# daemon app can access a custom Web API protected with MSAL.NET and OAuth2 scopes. As of now, I see no way of doing this.

The versions of the libraries and toolsets are:

.NET Core 2.2
Microsoft.Identity.Client 4.1.0

The client is

```
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("<client app id>")
                .WithClientSecret("<client_secret>")
                .WithAuthority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id_that_hosts_the_web_api>")
                .Build();
```

and then to acquire token

```
await app.AcquireTokenForClient(new string[] { "api://<app_id_of_the_web_api>/.default" });
```

At this point, I do get the token back with which I call my custom Web API end point protected using MSAL and an Azure App with the above mentioned App ID. This doesn't work since I have a policy based authorization on the end point, expecting a specific custom scope defined in the Azure AD app.

The question is, how do I configure the client and Azure AD so I will get the specific scopes passed in as claims for the Web API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register two applications, one for daemon app(client app), one for web api(backend app).

[image]

Click the web api app->Expose an API.
[image]

Click the daemon app->API permissions->Add a permission->My APIs->choose web api app->select the permissions.

[image]

Then the client

```
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("<client app id>")
                .WithClientSecret("<client app client_secret>")
                .WithAuthority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>")
                .Build();
```

The scope:

```
await app.AcquireTokenForClient(new string[] { "api://<app_id_of_the_web_api>/read" });
```

Refer to this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2). You can think of your web api as Microsoft Graph API.

Comment: Many thanks Caiyi! Let me give it a go and will let you know how I get on

Comment: Right, so after a bit of experimentation I found that scopes don't work in the context of Daemon apps. I need to use a combination of scopes and roles. I am posting my answer to my question.  +1 for the pointers above.

Answer (score 1):

First of all thanks much, Caiyi, for the pointers. That got me thinking the right way about the approach. Unfortunately, I am forced to use the api:///.default to get an access token. No amount of cajoling seems to work when using a "regular" scope. I configured the apps as was suggested above, but instead of:

```
await app.AcquireTokenForClient(new string[] { "api://<app_id_of_the_web_api>/read" });
```

I had to use:

```
await app.AcquireTokenForClient(new string[] { "api://<app_id_of_the_web_api>/.default" });
```

In the configuration for the API app, I had to define an "appRole" in the manifest that identifies the role that I was going to assign the Daemon app and then in the Web API, I changed my policy code to check for the scopes OR the app role - which worked.

Comment: Worked for me as well. Hard to find out with 1001 samples and continuously evolving libraries. In my web api i'm using services.AddProtectedWebApi(Configuration); and then it checks for scopes or roles. Getting a token for .default is required as a deamon app so it has to contain a role then else exception "Neither scope or roles claim was found in the bearer token." is thrown